# .NET MVC Explicit Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hey, one more newbie here, just playing around with .NET MVC. My main task is to have a few semi-static pages on URLs like:

- /about/
- /about/contacts/
- /about/jobs/

I'm using a controller for that called Static and have the following route attached:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "About",
  "about/{id}",
  new { controller = "Static", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

It seems to work fine as I have the Static controller with the Index method which uses a switch statement to identify which page has to be viewed. I use the RedirectToAction() function to call other actions of the Static controller in order to display pages with other views. My views are:

- /Static/About.aspx
- /Static/Contacts.aspx
- /Static/Jobs.aspx

This method seems to work fine, but what I don't like about it is the redirect, so browsing to /about/contacts I get a redirect to /Static/Contacts which is not what I'd really like to see in the URL.

So my question is - what is the correct way of doing this? And is there a way to explicitly call a certain view from my Index action?

Thanks,
~ K.

Comment: +1 good question for static routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do the redirect.  Instead of using a switch statement within the Index action, have a separate action for each page (ie. About, Contacts, Job) each with their own view.

Your `Static` controller could look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Contacts()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Jobs()
{
    return View();
}
```

And if you needed to do any processing specific to `Contacts` or `Jobs`, it can be done within their respective actions.

To explicitly call a certain view:

```
return View("ViewName");
```

There are seven overloads for the `View()` method.  A number of which allow you to pass the Model:

```
return View("ViewName", Model);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answers were correct, and perhaps my question wasn't. I used your suggestions to create my Static controller and had the About, Contacts and Jobs actions, routed them and it all seems to work fine. Only concern is the upper-cases in the URL ;)

Comment: Perhaps one more question about explicitly calling a view is, how to call a View explicitly AND pass it some View Model?

Comment: @kovshenin: I'm sorry.  It should be `return View("ViewName")`.  I'll edit the answer above.  As far as the upper-case URLs, why are you concerned?  I am assuming this is running on IIS, which has case-insensitive URLs.  `http://yourdomain.com/About` will be treated the same as `http://yourdomain.com/about`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend moving away from `Static`, and have an `About` controller. Within that controller, one method per page.

```
public ActionResult About() 
{
   return View ("About");
}

//Jobs() and Contacts() follow the same pattern
```

3 routes to match:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Jobs",
  "about/jobs",
  new { controller = "About", action = "Jobs" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Contact",
  "about/contact",
  new { controller = "About", action = "Contact"  }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "About",
  "about/",
  new { controller = "About", action = "About" }
);
```

Comment: you dont need those 3 routes, the default route will work perfectly.

Comment: I agree with the post and the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

you cant return views from a different controller and have the first controller in the URL.

the only way is use your about controller.

so place your logic in your about controller.

i have the same for myself in my Admin controller. it's just a page with some static links, and some extra pages.

in the index.aspx i have

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Evaluaties", "Evaluaties", "Admin")%></li>
    <li>
        <%= Html.ActionLink("ONAS aanbieders", "Index", "ONASAanbieder")%></li>
    <li>
        <%= Html.ActionLink("ONAS aanbod", "Index", "ONASAanbod")%></li>
    <li>
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Helpbox", "Index", "HelpBox")%></li>
</ul>
```

in the controller I have

```
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Evaluaties() {
        return View();
    }
```

this works like you described, no need to alter the routes.
obviously i have an `Evaluaties.aspx` in my `Admin` folder in the `Views` folder.

gives me this URL: `http://localhost:50152/Admin/Evaluaties`